# For an analytic function $f(z)=\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_nz^n$ in a disk of radius $R$, show that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2R^{2n}\leq M^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

We are supposing that $f(z)=\sum_0^{\infty}a_nz^n$ is analytic in $\{z:|z|<R\}$ and continuous in $\{z:|z|\leq R\}$. Denote $M=\max_{|z|\leq R}|f(z)|$.

We want to show that $|a_n|R^n\leq M$ for all $n$, and more generally $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2R^{2n}\leq M^2.$$

I am comfortable with showing the first part by using Cauchy's inequality and Integral formula. Given $f(z)=\sum_0^{\infty}a_nz^n$, we have
$$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}\ d\zeta=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}.$$ Thus
\begin{align*}
|a_n|R^n &=\left|\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right|R^n\\
&=\frac{R^n}{n!}|f^{(n)}(0)|\\
&\leq \frac{R^n}{n!} \frac{n!M}{R^n}\quad\text{(by Cauchy's inequality)}\\
&=M.
\end{align*}
I am not sure how to proceed to show the more general case. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_r(\theta)=f(re^{i\theta})$ for $r>0$, according to Parseval's identity we have
$$ \sum_{p\in\mathbb{Z}}|c_p(f_r)|^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f_r(\theta)|^2d\theta\leqslant M^2 $$
However
$$ c_p(f_r)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(re^{i\theta})e^{-ip\theta}d\theta=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a_n r^n}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i(n-p)}d\theta =a_pr^p$$
that ends the proof.

Comment: Ok. I'm not familiar with this identity, but it seems like it suffices to show that $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2\ d\theta=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}.$$